# How can I build a haskell dependency from a GitHub source .nix file, using nix?

Tags: haskell, nix

Ok, so I have a .nix file for my project that looks like this:

```
{ mkDerivation, base, blaze-html, clay, hakyll, hspec, stdenv }:
mkDerivation {
  pname = "open-editions";
  version = "0.1.0.0";
  src = ./.;
  isLibrary = false;
  isExecutable = true;
  executableHaskellDepends = [ base blaze-html clay hakyll ];
  testHaskellDepends = [ hspec ];
  license = "unknown";
  hydraPlatforms = stdenv.lib.platforms.none;
}
```

(It's just a web project using hakyll.) The problem is, `clay` is broken in nixpkgs. But I'm assuming `clay` works on its master branch on GitHub. So how can I replace this haskell dependency `clay` with something that downloads and calls the GitHub package? The GitHub package has a bunch of .nix files there, so I'm guess it'd be relatively straightforward, but I don't really know where to start on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend your haskell package set, similar to [this example](https://github.com/nix-community/todomvc-nix/blob/master/nix/backend/default.nix#L3).

The nix file for `clay` can be created with `cabal2nix`

```
cabal2nix git://github.com/sebastiaanvisser/clay.git > clay.nix
```

Assuming your .nix file is called `open-editions.nix`, your `default.nix` may look somewhat like:

```
let
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {}; # or similar, I like to pin it with niv

  hs = pkgs.haskellPackages.extend(self: super: { # (1) extend the package set
    open-editions = self.callPackage ./open-editions.nix {};
    clay = self.callPackage ./clay.nix {}; # (2) update clay
  });
in {
  inherit (hs) open-editions; # (3) make nix-build pick up my-project;
}
```

Comment: I can't quite get that to work. I get `Setup: Encountered missing dependencies:
hspec >=2.2.0 && <2.6, hspec-discover >=2.2.0 && <2.6`.

Comment: Sometimes version bounds are too strict, or you may need to override multiple packages. In this case, you can also choose to ignore the tests. Some packages are easier to get right on a recent package set. See [haskell.lib](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/lib.nix), in particular `doJailbreak`, `dontCheck`.